# How can I completely remove new Microsoft Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, file, uninstallation

I recently installed [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) right after the day it was launched. It consumed 20 gb of my disc space, so I decided to remove it. I went in to the applications folder and moved recently installed components associated with the installation to the trash. But it did not free any space at all. So I searched online and followed the following link for uninstallation: [Uninstalling Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/)

After following the link and entering all the terminal commands, I was only able to free up 10 gb of storage. How do I free up the rest 10 gb of the storage ?

Comment: Hi Shrijan Aryal, does your issue is solved or not?

Comment: @Sara-MSFT no my issue has not yet been resolved

Comment: What's your current status? You need to get rid of associated file through Library (Application support/Caches/Containers/Frameworks/Logs/Preference/Saved/LaunchAgents/LaunchDaemons/PrivilegedHelperTools/Saved Application State/) and the file in your user library folders like /System/Library (LaunchDaemons/LaunchAgents /private-tmp). Or you can use search in Library to enter the app’s name into the search bar at the top right of Finder and select the “Library” option or “This Mac” option next to “Search” to search, then remove those associated file and empty Trash and restart the computer.

Comment: I'm not worried about the disk space, but would very much like to remove all the ancillary processes that Visual Studio used to use but which are killing my Mac:-(

Comment: @ukayer Please refer to the answer I posted. I watched a YouTube video to be able to successfully remove all traces of VS on my mac. I wrote what I learned from the video in my answer.

Comment: @ShrijanAryal I found the source of my problem. Processes related to saving data were thrashing because I was relatively low on disk space. This is what caused my high CPU usage. The strange processes that I thought were left over turned out not to be MSFT processes but were also thrashing and bringing my machine to its knees. All sorted now and I will try reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: @ShrijanAryal I like DaisyDisk for exploring my hard drive for mysterious large space hogs. You might be able to find the other 10GB that way.

Comment: There is an [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall) on uninstalling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luckily I was able to solve this big trouble. I downloaded and installed an application called OmniDiskSweeper, and scanned my disk. The app immediately displayed 16 gb of traces of the Visual Studio and I deleted them all to free up all the space. The link to the download is: [this](http://snazzy.fm/omni)

Answer (score 13):

Current version Of MS VS takes 20GB on a macOs drive.

Please read the script to avoid removing shared stuff like Mono, NuGet & Visual Studio Code traces if it is needed by another app on your Mac.

Following script will free 20GB of space. Just put it in "uninstall.sh" file and run via terminal as "sudo ./uninstall.sh" (Do not forget to set to set execute permission on the file):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Complete uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio (Xamarin) including Mono and Microsoft NuGet traces:

# Uninstall Xamarin Studio
rm -rf "/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app"
rm -rf "/Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app"
rm -rf "/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app"
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-*
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/XamarinStudio-*
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/XamarinStudio-*
rm -rf ~/Library/XamarinStudio-*
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xamarin
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/XamarinStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/Xamarin
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/Xamarin
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Xamarin
rm -rf ~/Library/MonoAndroid
rm -rf ~/Library/XamarinStudio-*
rm -rf ~/Library/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/XamarinStudio-*
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/.templateengine/Visual\ Studio
rm -rf ~/.share/Xamarin
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Xamarin

sudo rm -f /private/var/db/receipts/com.xamarin.*
sudo rm -f /private/var/db/receipts/xamarin.*

# Uninstall Mono MDK
# You will also want to make sure that there are no other dependencies on Mono
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.mono-MDK.pkg
rm -rf ~/.local/share/MonoForAndroid
rm -rf ~/.config/.mono
rm -rf ~/.android

# Uninstall Xamarin.Android
sudo rm -rf /Developer/MonoDroid
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.android.pkg
rm -rf ~/Library/MonoAndroid

# Uninstall Xamarin.iOS
rm -rf ~/Library/MonoTouch
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework
sudo rm -rf /Developer/MonoTouch
sudo rm -rf /Developer/MonoAndroid
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.monotouch.pkg
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.xamarin-ios-build-host.pkg

## To Uninstall the Xamarin Build Host
 sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Xamarin.iOS Build Host.app"

## To unload and remove the Xamarin Build Host launchd job
 launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.xamarin.mtvs.buildserver.plist
sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchAgents/com.xamarin.mtvs.buildserver.plist

# Uninstall Xamarin.Mac
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework
rm -rf ~/Library/Xamarin.Mac
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Interactive.framework

# Uninstall Xamarin Installer
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller/
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/XamarinInstaller/
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/Xamarin/

# Uninstall Microsoft NuGet
rm -rf ~/.local/share/NuGet
rm -rf ~/.config/NuGet
rm -rf ~/.config/.NuGet
rm -rf ~/.NuGet

# Uninstall traces of visual studio code
rm -rf ~/.vscode
```

Comment: Although they share the name, Visual Studio Code is not part of Visual Studio for Mac. IMO your script should not try to remove the `~/.vscode` directory where user's VSCode extensions are installed

Comment: Beyond a doubt the best answer. It does work

Answer (score 4):

The following link seem to indicate how to remove VS For Mac
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/#Using_the_Uninstall_Script

Answer (score 2):

After you moved the installed components to the Trash, you should empty Trash that will free several hundreds MB size. To remove other remaining components or files, you can check the installer log in ~/Library/Logs/XamarinInstaller/Universal as [Sandy’s recommend](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/11/16/visual-studio-for-mac/) and John Smith found the various things mainly in Library/Frameworks manually removed. All-in-all came to about 14Gb worth so basically most of it.

After that, you can have a look at the following folders and think about remove those files which modified date or created date is the same time when you installed the VS for Mac on your computer. (you can backup it before you remove them)

~/Library/Application Support/

~/Library/Preferences

~/Library/Caches

~/Library/Logs/

/Developer/MonoAndroid

Answer (score 1):

I manually uninstall [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/):

1) remove main application

```
rm -R "/Applications/Visual Studio.app"
```

2) if you don't want or if you are not using package manager [Microsoft NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) remove it

```
rm -R "./.nuget"
```

3) and search for some possible remains

```
find . -type d \( -path /{{some_excluded_path}} -o -path /{{some_excluded_path}} -o -path /{{some_excluded_path}} \) -prune -o -print | grep "xamarin"
find . -type d \( -path /{{some_excluded_path}} -o -path /{{some_excluded_path}} -o -path /{{some_excluded_path}} \) -prune -o -print | grep "visual studio"
```

It maybe help.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has provided the guide to remove VS for Mac at here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall

For example, to remove all traces of Visual Studio for Mac, you can run following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Visual Studio.app"
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio
rm -rf "~/Library/Preferences/Visual Studio"
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/VisualLodStudio
```